# For every set $X$, is there a subset $Y⊆X$, such that $Y ∉ X$ and $Y ≠ X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $Y=X$, we can prove that $Y ∉ X$, but does there exist any other subset $⊆X$ in which this holds?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Two counterexamples would be $X=\varnothing$ or $X=\{\varnothing\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not generally true because of the counterexamples provided by Troposphere, however, these are the only counterexamples possible: for any other set $X$ there does exist a $Y\subset X$ such that $Y\neq X$ and $Y\notin X$.

For any set $X$ we have $\varnothing\subset X$, thus if $\varnothing\notin X$ and $X\neq \varnothing$, then there does exist a $Y$ as required. Therefore, your claim holds for any singleton set $\{a\}$ with $a\neq \varnothing$.

Furthermore, for any set with size $|X|\geq2$, there are $2^{|X|}$ subsets of $X$, thus necessarily there must be a subset not contained in $X$ that is unequal to $X$ itself.